# Sunspot: to return nothing when keyword is empty

Tags: sunspot

I want Sunspot to return nothing if the keyword is an empty string. Currently empty keyword will return all results.

I can't check that and return an empty array. This is because I am using Kaminari paginate and it does not recognize empty array as paginate-able.

Answer (score 1):

You could just return a paginated kaminari empty array by doing this:

```
Kaminari.paginate_array([])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running rails? You could create a conditional statement around the search and pagination.. something like "unless keyword.blank?"

Comment: yeah that's what I am doing: setting @collecton = nil; only paginate in view if it is not nil. I am just wondering if there is a dry-er way to do it

Comment: Not from what I have seen. If it is nil it will only search where the keyword is nil. I think you need to do and unless value.present?